# I am facing issues while installing appium in my machine

Tags: appium-ios

I am using following specifications

- MAC OS – 10.12.5
- Xcode –  8.3.3
- Appium – 1.6.4

Please help

Comment: Help with what issue? You'll need to edit your question and post more details for someone to review and help...

Comment: what issue you are facing